# How to get the client's IP address from python-socketio connection and still be able to emit from anywhere in the program

Tags: python, socket.io, ip

I have a Pyhton server that accepts SocketIO connections using the following [pyhton-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio) GitHub project. I would like to get the clients IP address when they connect. How can I get the **client's IP address**?

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
import threading
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socket = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True)


class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = thread_id

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        serve()
        print("Exiting " + self.name)


    def serve():
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)

@socket.on('connect')
    def connect():
        print("IP = ")  # print out client IP address here
```

Is there some way I can get the IP using the SocketIO instance?

I see I can get the IP by doing the following:

```
import socketio
sio = socketio.Server()
@sio.on('connect')
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('IP->' + environ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

But this then takes away emit functionality from anywhere in the program. This means that I can then only emit from inside the above connect() function.

**Is there anyway I can get the client IP and still be able to emit from anywhere in the program?**

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the IP address, store it a global variable, then you can do anything with that variable anywhere else

for instance:

```
IP = "0.0.0.0"
def connect(sid, environ):
    global IP
    print('IP->' + environ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    IP = environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
```